# accessing the values of class in jsp page from the action class

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I am doing one project on Struts 2 that I am getting knowledge little by little bit..

I have the action like this

```
<action name="backaction" class="HandlerAction">

<result name="user_profile" type="redirect">hai.jsp</result>
```

In the class Handler action I have the object `userprofile` in which the `name` and `age` are members.

In the execute function

```
log.info(userprofile.getName())//it is giving name xyz

return "user_profile"
```

I am getting hai.jsp but I am unable to retreive the value in that object `userprofile` in jsp.

hai.jsp is as follows..

```
<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<html>
<body>
<s:textfield name="user_name" value="%{userprofile.name}"/>

</body>
</html>
```

I tried by putting as `value="%{name}"` also but i am not getting the value xyz..

Comment: when i remove the type="redirect"...the sameclass backaction is iteratively executing and going to infinite..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with

```
<result name="user_profile" type="redirect">hai.jsp</result>
```

since you are using redirect result type which means that framework will create a new Request and response object and discarding old request/response Object.So when you are returning from your action your user-object is theirs in the value stack till you tell S2 that you want to use `redirect` result type.

On seeing redirect result type, it will discard any existing data and will create a new request for you place its content in value stack and that's why this is not working for you.I am not sure why you using `redirect` result type since you can do the same using any build in result type say `success`.

If you still want to use redirect result, i suggest you to save the user-profile data in either `Session` and retrieve it in your next action or use [scope-interceptor](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/scope-interceptor.html)

Comment: when i use the result success..it is going to the action of the index.jsp submit action..(i.e when user click submit button it will generate the action...).

Comment: i am not sure what you mean by going to action of index.jsp, since you can create any result string and show the view as per your requirements.

Comment: sorry...it is able to go to handleraction...but somehow the token or something like that is missing...i do not know the reason why...any way thanks for helping..i have been trying since 3 hours..you have helped your maximum.

Answer (score 1):

[Struts2 Redirect Result](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/redirect-result.html)

Calls the {@link HttpServletResponse#sendRedirect(String) sendRedirect} method to the location specified. The response is told to redirect the browser to the specified location (a new request from the client). The consequence of doing this means that the action (**action instance, action errors, field errors, etc**) that was just executed is lost and no longer available. This is because actions are built on a single-thread model. The only way to pass data is through the session or with web parameters (url?name=value) which can be OGNL expressions.